# Visulazing a specific value of a column with the corresponding values

Tags: python, data-mining, pandas, visualization, data-cleaning

I have recently started using **data studio** to make visualizations before diving into analysis and data prep!

I have a column named **NAME OF STORE** that good different names and other columns like Date, Number of fans, Number of Visitors, etc. For each store, at each date, I got different values for the other column.

How, can I choose in data studio what store I wanna make visualization for?

Comment: So, your question has nothing to do with python and pandas? Cuz you have them as tags but you ask about Data Studio.